# How many Convex and Odd functions exist?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

During lunch this question popped on mind.

How many odd and convex functions $f: R \to R $ exist ?

I guessed just 1, namely $f(x)=ax$  where $a$ is a fixed real number. But I couldn't either prove it or provide counter example.

Comment: @user376343 Convexity implies continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scalar multiples of $x$ are the only examples.

To see why, suppose you're given $(1, f(1))$ as well as $(0, 0) = (0, f(0))$. Draw the line connecting these two points, as well as its extension through $(-1, f(-1))$.

Since $f$ is convex, its graph for $0 < x < 1$ lies on or below this line. If the graph ever dips below the line, then using the oddness of $f$ implies that it gets above the line connecting $-1$ and $0$, contradicting convexity.

Hence, $f$ must agree with a straight line for $x \in (0, 1)$. It's not hard to extend this argument to $\mathbb{R}$.